Guy from a future gets transmigrated to a murim world with a system but he is a higher dimensional being so the system can't take control of him
Looking for a murim manhua where the mc gets killed by a woman in the future. He gets transmigrated into a murim world, but his world had more rules so he's a higher dimensional being. The system can't take control of him and proposes a master-slave relationship with the mc. (I don't know anything more, sorry)

Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE! When did you read this? was this in colour or black-and-white?
